# Lattice - moving the location of the strip in a barchart

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, lattice, strip

How do I *change the location* of the strip in a lattice barchart. The strip defaults to the top of the barchart but I would like to move it to the bottom of the barchart.

I've tried playing with `barchart(..., strip=strip.custom())` but I can't seem to move it at all.

Comment: Need data and code. Making us guess about your data layout is unacceptable.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought the question was basic enough to not need to be tailored to a particular data layout.

Comment: `strip.custom` is a wrapper to change the fixed arguments to `strip.default`, which don't seem to allow placing at the bottom.  You could write your own strip function. Type `strip.default` to see the code and modify the viewport placement - assuming you know your way around in `grid`.